# Sublime Text 3 - Shortcut to Pane Resizing?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I love Sublime Text. I work with 2 panes (columns) open, jumping from one to the other. Whenever going from one pane to the other, I typically resize it some amount. To do this, I must position the mouse over just right of the vertical scrollbar until I see the double horizontal arrows appear. Sometimes it's a pain to hit just the right spot to grip for resizing.

I've used other apps where there's a shortcut key that automatically snaps me to horizontal resizing arrows. Is there such a shortcut key (or package) in Sublime Text? My searching has turned up empty handed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Open

> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User

and add

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+super+left"]
    ,"command": "set_layout"
    ,"args": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.75, 1.0]
        ,"rows": [0.0, 1.0]
        ,"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
  },
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+super+right"]
    ,"command": "set_layout"
    ,"args": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.25, 1.0]
        ,"rows": [0.0, 1.0]
        ,"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
  },
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+super+up"]
    ,"command": "set_layout"
    ,"args": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        ,"rows": [0.0, 1.0]
        ,"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    }
  }
```

ctrl + super + left = enlarges left pane

ctrl + super + right = enlarges right pane

ctrl + super + up = makes both panes same size

Answer (score 11):

Check out the package [Origami](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Origami).

It has zoom mode and `origami_auto_zoom_on_focus`.

Answer (score 6):

The [PanePane](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PanePane) sublime package will allow you to resize panes via keyboard shortcuts.

- Package Control: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PanePane
- GitHub: https://github.com/mjsmith1028/PanePane

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Origami](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Origami) with `origami_auto_zoom_on_focus` **in addition to** <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> to reset the panes.

```
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+super+left"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]],
    },
  },
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+super+right"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args": {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]],
    },
  },
```

On my Mac I use Spectacle with similar bindings, but on <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd>